# jquery .animate() transform scale

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use the `transform: scale()` css propriety in the `.animate()` function in jQuery?

This, here, doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.circ1').animate({
    transform: 'scale(1)'
  }, 830);
});
```

Comment: You can see [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243887/how-to-do-a-transform-scale-animation-with-jquery)